# Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ converges to some $a>0$. Prove that there exists $N$ such that $a_n>0$ for all $n\geq N$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove the following:
Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ converges to some $a>0$. Prove that there exists $N$ such that $a_n>0$ for all $n\geq N$.\

I'm a little stuck because by the definition of convergence, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$. This definition already tells us that an $N$ exists, so I'm not sure how to go about the proof.

Comment: take $\varepsilon=a>0$

Comment: The definition doesn't directly tell you that such an N exists. The two things are not really equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\epsilon=a/2$.

Then there exists $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$

The last inequality is equivalent to

$$|a_n-a|<a/2$$

$$ -a/2 < a_n-a < a/2$$

$$ a/2 < a_n < 3a/2$$

From the last double inequality it's obvious that $a_n > 0$ for all $n\geq N$
(because $a$ itself is greater than zero).